# HTTPステータス 500 エラーの調査及び解決方法を教えてください

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Javaの経験は浅いです。
Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 直下のlogを見ましたけど、特に異常はなさそうです。
下記のエラーの解消方法を教えていただけますか？

**HTTPステータス**

> 500 -

**type 例外レポート メッセージ**

**説明**

> The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**例外**

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1938)
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1905)
pds.document.provider.PosFile.parseTag(PosFile.java:104)
pds.document.provider.PatentDocument.init(PatentDocument.java:66)
pds.servlet.ShowPatentDocument.showPatentDocumentImpl(ShowPatentDocument.java:116)
pds.servlet.ShowPatentDocument.doPost(ShowPatentDocument.java:74)
pds.servlet.ShowPatentDocument.doGet(ShowPatentDocument.java:38)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

**注意**

> 原因のすべてのスタックトレースは、Apache Tomcat/6.0.20のログに記録されています

Comment: 文字列の部分文字列を得るところで添字の範囲エラーなのでは？

Comment: 自分で作ったものではないので、どこから調査するのはよくわかりません。
できましたら、もう少し詳しい説明をいただけませんか。

Comment: エラーログで表示されている部分のソースを調べましょう。ソースが無い場合直しようはありません。作成者に報告しましょう。

Comment: もしかして例外が何か分かっていないって事はありませんよね？

Comment: ”StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:  String index out of range: -9"なのですから、文字列のインデックスに、負の値(-9)を指定した事が直接の原因。　何故、そうなったのかはソースプログラムでインデックスの値を計算している辺りを調べてください。

Comment: 長く使ってきたもので変更されないと思います。
JARファイルしかないみたいです。

Comment: 変更されないってどういうことでしょう？全部推測ですが、入力となった情報が誤っていて、そのバリデーションがザルで、exception発生しちゃってるんでしょうけど...じゃぁ入力データのどこがおかしいの？ってなると現状の情報からだけでは誰も分からないと思いますよ。

Answer (score 4):

Tomcatを使っていてHTTPステータス500エラーが出るのは、大抵の場合は、デプロイしたWebアプリにバグがあるか、何らかの設定が誤っているかのいずれかです。

具体的な原因を知るためには出力されたログを解析する必要があります。
本件質問のスタックトレースで注目すべき箇所は次のところです。

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1938)
 :
pds.document.provider.PosFile.parseTag(PosFile.java:104)
pds.document.provider.PatentDocument.init(PatentDocument.java:66)
```

エラーが出た直接の原因は

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1938)
```

とあるように、文字列の中をsubstring()で参照しようとしたときに負の値を指定したことによるものです。
[Java API String substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-)

ではどこで負の値を指定したのかというと、

```
pds.document.provider.PosFile.parseTag(PosFile.java:104)
```

となっているので `PosFile.java` の104行目の可能性が高いです。
おそらく`PosFile.parseTag()`メソッドに何らかのバグがあるのでしょう。あるいは`parseTag()`メソッドに渡される引数に誤りがあるのでしょう。具体的なことは該当するソースを見ないとわかりません。
もしかすると、クラス名やメソッド名から察するにposファイルとやらの内容を解析しているようなので、そのposファイル自体が本来満たしているべき規約や規格に添っていない可能性もあります。

---

スタックトレースの見方については以下のリンクが参考になると思います。

- [デバッグのヒント教えます（2）：スタックトレースからデバッグのヒントを読み取る - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0605/20/news012.html)

Answer (score 3):

何らかのソフトウェア製品を使われていてその利用上で生じているエラーのようですので、メーカーのサポート窓口に問い合わせてください。

Comment: http://www.raytec.co.jp/products/patlist/cnweb.pdf ではないでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

長く使っていたもので、アプリケーションを修正出来ないとすれば、使い方に問題がある可能性もありますね。スタックトレースの情報から 何かしらの入力された文字数が短すぎるか、添字の計算が間違っていると推測できます。

このエラーに再現性があるのであれば、異常時と正常時のデータを比較して、
普段の使い方と違うところがないか確認するとなにか分かるかもしれません。

また、JAR しか無いのは紛失したのでしょうか？
それとも ソースコードにアクセスする権限がないのでしょうか。
その辺を確認して開発元なり、所有者に問合せしてみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: たくさんのご回答をいただき、ありがとうございます。

確認させていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

jarしかないとコメントにありますが、
Tomcatでアプリケーションを動かしている場合、下記のディレクトリにアプリケーションのwarが展開されたフォルダが必ずあり、
展開前のwarファイルも存在する可能性が高いです。

$tomcat_home/webapps

tomcatのディレクトリがApache Tomcat/6.0.20であれば、下記のディレクトリになると思います。
Apache Tomcat/6.0.20/webapps

あと、気になった点が１点あります。
質問では「Apache Tomcat/6.0.20直下のlogを見た」とありますが、
通常Tomcatのログは以下のディレクトリにcatalina.outというファイル名で出力されます。
$tomcat_home/logs

Apache Tomcat/6.0.20/logs/catalina.out
というファイルはありませんか？

Comment: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20/logs/catalina.out あります。

いろいろ調べましたら、バッチ処理はうまくできなかったので、作りべきのファイルは作れなかった。
バッチ処理中に以下のコマンドラインはあります。
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp lib/PDSIndexCreator.jar pds.indexCreator.IndexCreator /opt/PDS/data/jpdata /opt/PDS >> $log 2>> $errlog

java -Xmx1536M -Xms1024M -cp lib/FTSPatentIndexer.jar:lib/xmldocument.jar

そのコマンドラインの意味はよくわかりません。
バッチ処理成功させるため、Xmxを大きくすればよいですか？

Comment: バッチ処理のコマンドの中にある$errlogという変数にバッチ処理のログ出力先が指定されているはずです。
失敗したバッチ処理のログを確認してはどうでしょうか？
バッチ処理がOutOfMemoryで失敗しているなら、Xmxを大きくすれば成功するかもしれません。
バッチ処理のエラーログもこちらに貼ってみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

add map:S0, value null!!
add map:TU, value null!!
....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "diff"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
 at pds.indexCreator.IndexCreator.addContent(IndexCreator.java:251)
 at pds.indexCreator.IndexCreator.updateCdromInfo(IndexCreator.java:215)
 at pds.indexCreator.IndexCreator.update(IndexCreator.java:132)
 at pds.indexCreator.IndexCreator.main(IndexCreator.java:71)

Comment: バッチ処理うまくできなかった原因は diffデータ不備があるとわかりました。
 diffのデータを除けば、ちゃんと処理ができて、すべてのエラーは解消しました。
たくさんの方々からアドバイスをいただき、ありがとうございました。